# Word - Abbreviation Index single Item not right aligned

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a case while creating an abbreviation index in my work where a single index is not right aligned while all other elements are.

[image]

The abbreviation in text is created like the others, i.e. PI {XE "PI" \t "Product Increment"} and it is the only entry of the index that seems not to work.

Any advice what could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the INDEX field generates its output, it applies paragraph styles name "Index 1" etc. (In the English language version of Word) to the entries.

It then uses a tab character to position the text ("Product Increment" in this case) at the right-aligned tab set in that style.

But the `Index 1` style, for example, is set up with a  0.15in (c. 0.38cm) Hanging indent.

That means that if you have an entry that is shorter than 0.38cm, the tab will only tab to the Hanging Indent position (even though no tab is explicitly defined at that indent).

All you other entries must be wider than that indent, so are properly tabbed.

I thought you might be able to work around this without changing the styles, by adding some form of space in your XE field, e.g.

```
{ XE "PI   " \t "Product Increment" }
```

but Word stripped all the whitespace types I tried (ordinary, non-breaking, m-space, tab), and it was the same when I tried putting a tab att the beginning of the "Product Increment" text.

So I think you have to modify the `Index 1` style so that the hanging indent is smaller or removed altogether.

To do that, you can click in the line cin the index that contains the PI entry, then click Alt-Ctrl-Shift-S (in Windows Word) to bring up the styles list. The correct style should be selected. If not, look for `Index 1` and select it.

Click the dropdown to the right of the style name, select *Modify...* . CLick the *Format* button at the bottom left of the dialog box, then click the *Paragraph...* option.

In there, modify the width in the Indentation->Special->By box to something that makes it work. It will depend on the typeface/font and point size of the index text, but 0.29cm / 0.1in both worked here. (They are not the same as each other!).

Then click OK and dismiss the dialog boxes.

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem!